# Rearrange columns into a table

Tags: variables, awk, text-processing

I have a space delimited file like this:

```
GID_1 AID_1 2
GID_1 AID_2 1
GID_1 AID_3 3
GID_2 AID_1 3
GID_2 AID_2 1
GID_2 AID_3 2
GID_3 AID_1 1
GID_3 AID_2 1
GID_3 AID_3 3
```

and I would like to transpose columns 1 and 3 by column 2 and have this:

```
(X)   GID_1 GID_2 GID_3
AID_1  2     3     1
AID_2  1     1     1
AID_3  3     2     3
```

I've put an "(X)" because this transposition will make that field to be blank, which is fine to me.

Please, can anyone help me on that?

Comment: This question is quite different from the suggested duplicate.

Comment: @Thor You're right. In the proposed duplicate row labels are unique.

Comment: Exactly, I don't see how the "duplicate" applies here... I want to transpose by "column 2", and in the duplicate they are just transposing everything...

Comment: @user2890714: I don't think this process is called transposition, I would rather say rearrange or reform or even tabularize.

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution

```
awk -F" |_" '
    {
    g=g>$2?g:$2
    a=a>$4?a:$4
    arr[$2 " " $4]=$5
    } 
    END {
    for (j=1;j<=g;j++)
        {
        printf "\tGID_%s",j
        }
    print ""
    for (i=1;i<=a;i++)
        {
        printf "AID_%s",i
        for (j=1;j<=g;j++)
            {
            printf "\t%s",arr[j " " i]
            }
        print ""
        }
    }
    ' file
        GID_1   GID_2   GID_3
AID_1   2       3       1
AID_2   1       1       1
AID_3   3       2       3
```